# combine multiple geojsons

Tags: polygon, geojson, merge, geotools

I have several geojsons which contain polygons. But the polygons are reaching over other geojsons. When I import them into lets say Qgis, the polygons, which are distributed among several geojsons are dissected. 
I need to merge these geojsons into one geojson and the polygons must be recognized and and merged correctly too. I would be happy about a java-solution (like geotools)

Comment: Then you should add GeoTools in your tags to raise concern on GeoTools experts.

Comment: ah right, thanks. I would also try other solutions though

Answer (score 2):

You can read in all the GeoJSON files and then loop through the polygons and select all from the collection that `touch` or `intersect` the current one, then merge the selected ones and repeat until no more touch.

So something like this should do it:

```
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
List<SimpleFeature> results = new ArrayList<>();
try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = col.features()) {
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature f = itr.next();

    Filter tFilter = ff.touches(ff.property(f.getDefaultGeometryProperty().getName()),
        ff.literal(f.getDefaultGeometry()));
    Filter iFilter = ff.intersects(ff.property(f.getDefaultGeometryProperty().getName()),
        ff.literal(f.getDefaultGeometry()));
    Or filter = ff.or(tFilter, iFilter);
    SimpleFeatureCollection selection = col.subCollection(filter);
    List<Geometry> geometries = new ArrayList<>();
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator it2 = selection.features()) {
      while (it2.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature f2 = it2.next();
        geometries.add((Geometry) f2.getDefaultGeometry());
      }
    }
    GeometryCollection geometryCollection = (GeometryCollection) gf.buildGeometry(geometries);

    Geometry union = geometryCollection.union();
    f.setDefaultGeometry(union);
    results.add(f);
  }

}
```